# Is excess noise in a resistor only present with DC?

Tags: resistors, noise

Resistor excess noise is present when DC current flows in a discontinuous material, for example through carbon granules in a carbon composition resistor. My question is: Why there is no excess noise when an AC current flows through a resistor?

Quoting (Motchenbatcher/Fitchen):

> *"Excess noise power is proportional to 1/f, and excess noise voltage*
> *is proportional to the level of DC flowing through a resistor."* p. 172

it continues:

> "*The noise index is the rms value of uV of noise in the resistor per V*
> *of DC drop across the resistor in a decade of frequency."* p. 173

And on page 19:

> *"... Thus, even though the noise is caused by current flow, it can be expressed in terms of the direct voltage drop rather than resistance
> or current"*.

Also, from this old document from Texas Instruments by P.D. Smith :[Noise in Precision Film Resistors](https://conradhoffman.com/papers_lib/TI_Noise_Prec_Resistors.pdf), on page 3 section 3 it says

> *"The RMS value of current noise is proportional to the d-c voltage*
> *across the resistor".*

As you can see, there is a lot of emphasis on being DC rather than AC what is causing excess noise.

Comment: Your question is flawed - noise is still generated irrespective of the type of current flow.

Comment: Where did you read that there is no excess noise when an AC current flows through a resistor?

Comment: @Sean I didn't specifically read that there is no excess noise when AC flows through a resistor, what I read is that excess noise is present when DC flows through a discontinous conductor such as a resistor (Motchenbatcher/Fitchen), the text does not mention excess noise by the presence of AC. The Noise index of a resistor is a measure of excess noise, which is calculated as uV/VDC per decade, again, the text is very specific on the current being DC and not AC.

Comment: @Andyaka to emphasize, if noise is still generated with AC, can it be calculated the same way as with DC? meaning, I can multiply the noise index by the AC volts and get the same result as if it were DC?

Comment: I would guess the text you read meant the presence of an *rms* current through the resistor (which can be a combination of AC or DC or both) causes this noise to appear.

Comment: @Sean I edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

There is excess noise in a carbon resistor when current flows through it. It doesn't matter whether that current changed direction in the past and will do again in the future, or is steady, the noise at any given current is the same.

The question is perhaps, why do people emphasise that noise is generated even when the current is DC?

One possibility is that it's unexpected to most people that a passive device like a resistor should generate noise in excess of its thermal noise when something as uninteresting as a DC current is flowing.

Another possibility is that when trying to measure or demonstrate the noise, it's trivial to get a very low noise source of DC. You only have to use larger and larger capacitors to ground, and you can suppress the supply noise to any given degree. It's rather more difficult to generate low noise AC.

The main reason is that the noise is 1/f noise, that it gets weaker as the frequency increases. So although the noise may be generated by an AC current, the noise will be modulated by that current, and will appear as sidebands around the drive frequency. This confounds the problem of measurement, as although it's relatively straightforward to measure noise at 1 Hz and 0.1 Hz from DC, getting that close to an AC signal requires exquisitely low phase noise sources, which themselves are corrupted by 1/f noise.

Comment: The Noise Index of a resistor is calculated as uV/VDC per decade acording to Motchenbatcher/Fitchen, so if I apply 10V to a 1uV/VDC resistor, noise over one decade of frequency will be 10uV. Are you saying I can get those 10uV irrespective of wheter the current is DC or AC? is it calculated the same way with AC than with DC and irrespective of frequency?

Comment: @S.s. Yes, but it will be more difficult to measure, as it will be modulated up onto the AC carrier. As a separate exercise, consider the decade 1 Hz to 10 Hz, now the decade 0.1 Hz to 1 Hz, now the one 10 mHz to 100 mHz, now the one ... You see where this is going, don't you? There are an infinite number of 'decades' as you head down in frequency, still without reaching DC. Does that mean the resistor generates an infinite amount of noise?

Comment: My aim is to calculate resistor noise, so in the end, should I also consider excess noise when AC is present and calculate it just the same way as I would with DC? regardless of wether its more difficult to measure or if the AC carrier is modulating the noise.

Answer (score 2):

A practical way to think of resistor excess noise is:

- The current flow causes noise in the *resistance value* of the component.
- Even if the current itself is completely noiseless.

Bearing this in mind, you will realize that AC measurements do not get around the resistor excess noise as correctly explained by Neil_UK.

One consequence of this is, that the excess noise creates a *physical limit* for the precision to which a resistor is measurable or even definable. No amount of integration time or probe currents gets you around this limit. For example, a 0 dB noise index resistor can be only measured/defined to a precision of 6.6e-7 or 0.67 ppm. This seems low but is a huge problem in metrology, hence the need for ultra stable <-40 dB resistors.